# How to store an array of CLLocationCoordinate2D in Core Data to draw a polyline?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, cllocationcoordinate2d

I want to store an array of `CLLocationCoordinate2D` in Core Data but this error always appears while executing the code [image: xcode screenshot]

> Thread 1: signal SIGABRT

Comment: Please include your code, especially the part where you're trying to save  the CLLocationCoordinate2D to Core Data.

Comment: how to save this array displayed in output in core data

Comment: @WalidNakbi Show your work. Edit your post and answer these questions for your audience: What did you find out about this error message when you googled it? What did you find out when you used the debugger to step through the code leading up to that error? What remedies have you tried, and what were the results? Don't tell me. Edit your question so everyone can see everything you've tried so they don't waste their time trying the same things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error says in the console:

> this archiver cannot encode structs

`CLLocationCoordinate2D` is a struct. Core Data can only store basic types like dates, numbers, data, strings etc. If you want to store a location coordinate just store its components (simply latitude and longitude) as doubles, and you can write a supporting method to initialize the `CLLocationCoordinate2D` struct from the numerical values.